# Python kernel crashed (win-64bit)

Tags: enthought

I am supporting a user who is trying to use Canopy. Every time she starts the program the kernel crashes. I installed the program myself and viewed another install which work fine. I believe her issue is that the .ipython and .matplotlib foders are not getting installed in her home directory.

The same issue arises with the 32-bit client after all updates are applied.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Do you have a traceback that you can share, to help debug?  Also, can you try removing the `User`(`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User`) and `System` (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System`) environments and restarting Canopy, to see if it fixes it?

Comment: @pattyd, Canopy is a Python programming library and development environment, so yes.

Comment: @punchagan I will try deleting those directories. How would you like me to send the log?

Comment: @punchagan Deleting those directories didn't work. You can view the log using this link: https://sendit.broadinstitute.org/files/download/schulsi/51b084fb2d0d6/package.zip